# Why does the following nodejs code not work with socketio+express 3?

Tags: node.js

I dont get why this does not work:

I have a sample.js containing:

```
var http = require('http');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log('Client Connected...');

    client.emit('messages', {hello: 'world'});
});

server.listen(8080);
```

I have an index.html page that contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="socket.io.js"></script>

        <script>
            var server = io.connect('http://mydomain:8080');
            server.on('messages', function(data) {
                alert(data.hello);
            });         
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update:** When using the socket.io-client.js library, when I go to the `http://mydomain:8080` page, I get an "info - unhandled socket.io url"

Can someone point out what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in your browser console?  The Socket.IO client-side code is usually served at `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

Comment: No errors in my java code, I moved the socket.io.js to the root level of my application directory. Changing it to <script src="node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"></script> does not appear to work either.

Comment: `node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js` is not the client-side component of Socket.IO.  You can find that code here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/

Comment: Or the Socket.IO server will make it available at `http://mydomain:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: @scttnlsn Why is it usually served at /socket.io/socket.io.js when it appears in the github of both socket.io and socket.io-client both have their .js in a lib directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server's never sending out `index.html` because you never told it to. You need something like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

assuming `index.html` is at the root level of your app, or, more generally:

```
app.use(express.static(__DIRNAME+'/public'));
```

and then put `index.html` (along with any other static files like stylesheets) in the `public` subdirectory of your app.